# How will you go about designing a sitemap if the website has no sub navigation?

Tags: sitemap

I am used to making a sitemap for websites that have sub-navigation's in them. What if it's a smaller website that has no sub-navigation? Will the sitemap look as simple as this?

```
           Home
  Portfolio-----About-----Contact
```

There is no sub-navigation to break it down more so will that be it or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What's wrong with that? I look for a ToC even in a 20 pages book...

Comment: **yes**. it's as simple as that, yo don't need to invent anything in order to have a sitemap "just because"

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

Yes is the answer to your question. Why would you invent additional levels?

## Sitemap - the term

The term sitemap is ambiguous, it may denote:

- The hierarchical navigation taxonomy
- A group of links at the bottom of a page providing the most relevant links to other parts of the site

  - Like at the bottom of this page
  - With an on-going argument regarding their contribution to SEO.

I guess you mean the former.